# How to call Nunit from Visual Studio in a batch file

Tags: visual-studio, nunit, batch-file

I have set my Visual Studio to start Nunit as an external program to run all the tests written in a module.

Now what I am trying to do is to create a batch file which will call Myproj.exe. What I am expecting is that it will run Nunit as I have set it to run an external program and execute all my tests in nunit.exe, but when I run that batch file it starts running from Visual Studio instead of opening NUnit.

Can any one please give me a clear idea as how to accomplish it?

I am too much stuck.

---

Now I am trying to run the following commands in shell

nunit-x86.exe
Can you please tell how should I load my visualbasic project file (exe) here and then run all the tests from here 
as unable to execute following command

```
nunit nunit.tests.vbproj /config:release
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make NUnit start everytime you debug your "NUnit tests".

You can attach the debugger in Visual Studio Express doing it [that](http://thespoke.net/forums/923583/ShowPost.aspx) way.
If you use a "full version" of VS do it that way:

> Note that if you’re using the full and
>   not the express version of Visual
>   Studio 2005, you can do this by
>   opening up the project’s properties,
>   and in the Debug tab select Start
>   External Program: and navigate to the
>   NUnit executable, and set
>   YourCompanyname.YourProject.Test.dll as the
>   Command Line Arguments.

I got that ideas from [this tutorial](http://www.taumuon.co.uk/jabuka/Tutorial2/Tutorial2_v1.pdf)(Page 4/5) and love it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run NUnit after every successful build in Visual Studio with a Post-Build Event.

In VS2005, right-click on the project that has your tests and select Properties. Then on the Build Events tab, in the "Post-build event command line", put this* to use the console:

```
nunit-console /xml:$(ProjectName).xml $(TargetPath)
```

or this to use the GUI::

```
nunit $(TargetPath) /run
```

In "Run the post-build event:", leave the default: "On successful build"

If you use the GUI, know that your build will appear to be hung up until you close the GUI app.

*NOTE: The nunit console [command line docs](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.4.8) say "By default the nunit-console program is not added to your path."

Answer (score 0):

you can just shell nunit.exe with the command line to your assembly to run tests in.

Answer (score 0):

You can load nUnit.exe (nUnit-Console.exe for command line execution) using external tool features in Visual studio. Once you add the command via external tools feature ([as explained in this blog](http://qtp-automate.blogspot.co.uk/2013/10/how-to-execute-invoke-nunit-from-visual.html)), you can use it for any project to execute the tests. (Other is to add through project properties but that needs to be done for every project). Also in the arguments you can pass /include or /exclude to include or exclude categories of the tests.

The advantage of this method is you need not worry about giving path to DLL file and it works for any project you are on and gets executed with few clicks